# How do I get my application to show up in the Open in... menu. Appcelerator

Tags: ios, types, titanium, appcelerator, document

I want to do the same thing that explains this article in the apple documentation, but in Appcelerator Titanium. I searched the Appcelerator website and did not find the way. Anyone know any?
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register for the files you want to be able to handle in your `tiapp.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <ios>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
                        <string>Add to Housters</string>
                        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                        <string>Viewer</string>
                        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
                        <string>Owner</string>
                        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
                        <array>
                            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
                            <string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
                        </array>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
</ti:app>
```

Then, in your application's code, every time the `resume` event is fired (for example, `Ti.App.addEventListener('resume', resume);`), you can look at `Ti.App.getArguments().url` to see if your app has been opened via another app. In my apps, I do that, plus I scan the `Inbox` folder to see if there's anything. When another app opens a document in your app, it gets copied in to this directory, and then your app is launched. So `Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'Inbox').getDirectoryListing() || []` will get you an array of all the documents in there, which you can then move out of that directory, or handle and delete.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have adapted your example to my application, changing the types by jpg, png and gif, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Good! That one was a bear to figure out, particularly the bit about looking in `Inbox` for files. (I'm too scared to look and see if that's a recommended practice, since it's working pretty well!)